# How to properly write unit tests that are not system dependant

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I've got a method `GetFileObject(string filePath)` that will either return `null` (if file represented by path does not exist) or return an instance of a `FileObject` class where `FileObject` is declared as follows:

```
public class FileObject
{
    public FileObject(string path, DateTime dateModified, DateTime dateCreated, Version version, long size)
    {
        Path = path;
        DateModified = dateModified;
        DateCreated = dateCreated;
        Version = version;
        Size = size;
    }

    public string Path {get;}

    public DateTime DateModified {get;}

    public DateTime DateCreated {get;}

    public Version Version {get;}

    public long Size {get;}
}
```

I'm now trying to write some unit tests for `GetFileObject(string filePath)`, but the way I see it is I can't Moq it (else I won't really be testing my method) and whatever path I specify is subjective to the system it's running on.

For example, if I wanted to check if it really returns null when a given path doesn't exist I would have to specify a valid file path and may be tempted to do `GetFileObject("X:\FileThatDoesNotExist.something")` - but whereas that may not exist on my system and the test may pass, there's no guarantee that won't exist on someone else's system.

Now verifying that a file does not exist could actually be made trivial by asking the system for a temp file, deleting the temp file and then checking its existance, but what about checking other aspects of the method? That it returns the accurate `Path`, `DateModified`, `DateCreated`, `Version` and `Size`? How can I create a test for that that's not bound to a system?

Comment: You can't test the system return expected result and be independent of the system. Maybe you can use standard .NET method in System.IO to some abstraction over the system.

Comment: If you want to mock a filesystem then there's [`System.IO.Abstractions`](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions). Without a specific test case and the definition of `GetFileObject` there's not much more we can help with.